# Pandas - why is read_csv with chunking 'on' faster than without for small files?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a somewhat large table (90*85000) of strings, integers and missing values into pandas. The file fits easily into my memory. I also ran the script on a server with plenty of memory, observing the same behavior.

I would assume that reading the file in bulk would be faster or as fast as with chunking. However, with 'chunksize=any_number' pandas reads the file almost 300 times faster (11.138s vs. 0.039s).

Can someone explain this behavior?

My code:

```
startTime = datetime.now()
df=pd.read_csv(dataFile,delim_whitespace=True)
print datetime.now() - startTime

startTime = datetime.now()
df=pd.read_csv(dataFile,delim_whitespace=True, chunksize=10)
print datetime.now() - startTime
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

because in the second part you've created a `pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader object` (iterator)...

Demo:

```
In [17]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(20, 3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [18]: df.to_csv('d:/temp/test.csv')

In [19]: reader = pd.read_csv('d:/temp/test.csv', chunksize=10, index_col=0)

In [20]: print(reader)
<pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader object at 0x000000000827CB70>
```

How to use this iterator

```
In [21]: for df in reader:
   ....:     print(df)
   ....:
   a  b  c
0  0  5  6
1  6  0  6
2  2  5  0
3  3  6  2
4  5  7  2
5  5  2  9
6  0  0  1
7  4  8  3
8  1  8  0
9  0  8  8
    a  b  c
10  7  9  1
11  6  7  9
12  7  3  2
13  6  4  4
14  7  4  1
15  2  6  5
16  5  2  2
17  9  9  7
18  4  9  0
19  0  1  9
```

In the first part of your code you've read the whole CSV file in one DF (Data Frame). Obviously it takes longer because the iterator object (`reader` in the demo above) doesn't read the data from the CSV file until you start to iterate over it

Example: let's create a 1M rows DF and compare the timing of `pd.read_csv(...)` and `pd.read_csv(..., chunksize=1000)`:

```
In [24]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10**6, 3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [25]: df.shape
Out[25]: (1000000, 3)

In [26]: df.to_csv('d:/temp/test.csv')

In [27]: %timeit pd.read_csv('d:/temp/test.csv', index_col=0)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.21 s per loop

In [28]: %timeit pd.read_csv('d:/temp/test.csv', index_col=0, chunksize=1000)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.42 ms per loop
```

Comment: Not even the first one I think :-) (as it just returns an iterator)

Comment: Nice answer. For the benefit of reader new to pandas I'd suggest you might make it explicit that in the first example the data has actually been read into a dataframe object, whereas in the second, the reader is created, but the data has not yet been read from disk.

Comment: @JRichardSnape, it's a good point, thank you! I've updated my answer

Comment: @MaxU thanks for the answer. It was not clear to me that the created iterator object does not read the file until it is being iterated over.

Comment: @Dahlai, you are welcome! :) Thanks for accepting the answer!